# Lightest infusable shield/weapon?

Tags: dark-souls-3

You can infuse a weapon/shield with simple or blessed gems, two-hand a weapon and still get the effect. My question is if there are some that can be used for that with the less weight. I know that most small shields weigh 1.5, but is there anything lighter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lightest infusable weapon is actually the [Caestus](http://darksouls3.wikidot.com/equipmentgroup:caestus) with a weight of 0.5. 
While the plank shield suggested in the other answer works too, I'd recommend infusing the Caestus instead because it has a lower weight and if you switch to one-handing your weapon, the plank shield has no use since it has horrible defense values, while the Caestus has the fastest parry animation in the game.

It's quite common to infuse it with blessed or simple gems to get the regeneration bonuses and still be able to parry in PVP.

Answer (score 4):

According to the Wiki, the lightest infusable shield is the [plank shield](http://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Plank+Shield).   The Wiki page states it is the lightest shield in the game, weighing in at a mighty 1, and that it is also infusable.

The Wiki also warns that it is not recommended since it does not have a parry, and it has poor damage and stability, but it seems you are just using the shield to get the benefits of the infused gems while two-handing a weapon.

But to answer the question, **the Plank Shield is the lightest infusable shield.**